# Spring JPA ddl-auto=create with initial data

Tags: database, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to create my tables using Spring JPA auto table creation after that I want to insert my own data (SQL).

To be able to do this I used these lines in my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.sql.init.data-locations=\
classpath:database/sectors_data.sql,\
classpath:database/users_data.sql
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

The problem is that when I use `ddl-auto=create` and run my application it creates tables but does not insert data. To make it to insert data I should change `ddl-auto=create` to `ddl-auto=update` and run my application again.

I want to know is there a way to make it with only one run, create tables and then insert data without using any db migration tools like `Flyway`.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please note that script-based initialization i.e. through schema.sql and data.sql and Hibernate initialization together can cause some issues.**

Either we disable Hibernate automatic schema creation:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

This will ensure that script-based initialization is performed using the `schema.sql` and `data.sql` files directly.

If we still want to have both Hibernate automatic schema generation in conjugation with script-based schema creation and data population, we'll have to use:

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

This will ensure, that after Hibernate schema creation is performed then additionally `schema.sql` is read for any additional schema changes and `data.sql` is executed to populate the database.

Also, script-based initialization is performed by default only for embedded databases, to always initialize a database using scripts, we'll have to use:

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

Refer to

- [Quick Guide on Loading Initial Data with Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql)
- [Initialize a Database Using Basic SQL Scripts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts)

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @ZootHii You are welcome. Happy to know it works.

Comment: @DevThiman about "_that after Hibernate schema creation is performed then additionally schema.sql is read for any additional schema changes_" Do you mean that `schema.sql` makes a complement of the current schema generated by the `@Entitites` classes?